# Oauth - can my application use Stellar Oauth?

Tags: stellar

Does Stellar have Oauth, or is it on your road-map ?

Comment: Why'd you remove the text here?

Answer (score 1):

Oauth isn't presently on our [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/Clb1VMP5/platform-roadmap), but feel free to check back in future.